# Zerif Lite Background slider image wordpress

Tags: php, html, image, background, slider

for the past week im trying to make my background image slide in Zerif Lite.

Also tried using big_title.php section, to add my slider code there, but the problem is that I need this title there as it is, and code pushes the title down... http://www.star-grooming.co.uk

can you suggest any alternative please?

Or how do I insert this     [masterslider id="1"] gallery without pushing the title away?

Thanks,

Gedi

```
 code for big_title section 




<?php


echo '<div class="header-content-wrap">';

    echo '<div class="container">';


    $zerif_bigtitle_title = get_theme_mod('zerif_bigtitle_title',__('ONE OF THE TOP 10 MOST POPULAR THEMES ON WORDPRESS.ORG','zerif-lite'));


    if( !empty($zerif_bigtitle_title) ):


        echo '<h1 class="intro-text">'.__($zerif_bigtitle_title,'zerif-lite').'</h1>';


    endif;





    $zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_label = get_theme_mod('zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_label',__('Features','zerif-lite'));


    $zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_url = get_theme_mod('zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_url', esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'#focus');





    $zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_label = get_theme_mod('zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_label',__("What's inside",'zerif-lite'));


    $zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_url = get_theme_mod('zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_url',esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'#focus');





    if( (!empty($zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_label) && !empty($zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_url)) ||


    (!empty($zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_label) && !empty($zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_url))):


        echo '<div class="buttons">';


            if ( !empty($zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_label) && !empty($zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_url) ):


                echo '<a href="'.$zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_url.'" class="btn btn-primary custom-button red-btn">'.__($zerif_bigtitle_redbutton_label,'zerif-lite').'</a>';


            endif;


            if ( !empty($zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_label) && !empty($zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_url) ):


                echo '<a href="'.$zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_url.'" class="btn btn-primary custom-button green-btn">'.__($zerif_bigtitle_greenbutton_label,'zerif-lite').'</a>';


            endif;


        echo '</div>';


    endif;





    echo '</div>';

echo '</div><!-- .header-content-wrap -->';

    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install other themes like "Be" - "The7" - "Enfold" - etc and use a page builder to customize your WP Site Whatever you love

if you use page builder , your site will be more flexible than this theme

Comment: Dont want to pay $$ for any themes, but thanks for suggestion  man!

Comment: you can find free versions of these themes easily ...... search more :) @gediminas-tam

Comment: this is the free version im using but i need to add external code, this is why im here...

Comment: [masterslider id="1"] is a shortcode , use a "echo" and put this to your PHP Code instead of Big Title Background like a simple page or post @gediminas-tam